# Measurement results of Wiener process (Brownian process)

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, mathematical-physics, brownian-motion, stochastic-approximation

In a physics text, "*Quantum Measurement Theory and it's Applications*" by Kurt Jacobs, it describes the idea of a "*continuous measurement*" (measurement taking place over time $T$): $$dy = x_{true}dt + \beta dW$$ with a term $\beta dW$ corresponding to Wiener noise (Brownian prcoess). It then defined the continuous measurement result after time $T$ as $$y := \int_{0}^{T}xdt + \beta \int_{0}^{T}dW$$ Equivalently it shows we can write $$dy = \langle x \rangle dt + \frac{dW}{\sqrt{8k}}$$ where $k$ is a constant.

It then states that the meaurement result can be written as $$y(t) = \langle x(t) \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{8k}} \xi(t)$$ where $\xi(t) := \frac{dW}{dt}.$ Can anyone see the reasoning for this last equation and specifically why we would take $\xi(t) := \frac{dW}{dt}$?

Comment: I'd say that last equation makes very little sense to be honest. But you haven't said what $k$ is.

Comment: I think generally the "derivative" of Brownian motion is considered [white noise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639320/what-is-white-noise-and-how-is-it-related-to-the-brownian-motion), i.e. the classic type of noise considered in signals.