# What is the meaning of a space-time white

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

For reference this is from page 27 [here](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/cmlr/Preprints/Utah-Summer-School.pdf)

Consider the stochastic heat equation
$$ \begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)=\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) +f(u(x,t))\dot{W}(x,t) & t >0, x\in[0,L]
\\ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(L,t)=0 &t>0
\\ u(x,0)=u_0(x) &x \in[0,L]
\end{cases} $$
$\dot{W}(x,s$) is refered to as the space-time white noise. But this doesn't make sense to the defintion of white noise given in the same text.

> $\textbf{White Noise}$ here is defined as follows: The gaussian process $\{\dot{W}(A)\}_{A \in \mathscr B(\mathbb R^n)}$ with $E(\dot{W}(A))=0$ and $E(\dot{W}(A)\dot{W}(B))=\lambda^n(A\cap B)$ where $\lambda ^n$ is the n-dimensianal Lesbegue measure is called White Noise.
>
> It then goes on to say that we can consider for $A \in \mathscr B(\mathbb R^n)$ that $\dot{W}(A) = \int 1_A dW$ and for $h\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ we define $\dot{W}(h) = \int h(t)dW(t)$ which is the standard Wiener Integral.

This is also the same definition given in the [Walsh notes](https://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Eathreya/archive/spde/Walsh.pdf)

So my question is, what is $\dot{W}(x,t)$? Could it be $\dot{W}(0\times t) \times (0,x])$?

Also how does this definition relate to the definitions given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639320/what-is-white-noise-and-how-is-it-related-to-the-brownian-motion)? In particular to notion that White noise, $\dot{W}$, is the weak derivitive of Brownian motion. Ie: If $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion then $\dot{W}$ is a distribution on the set of test functions such that $$ -\int W_t\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(t)dt=\int\dot{W}_t\phi(t)dt $$

Comment: You should probably construct a sequence of distributions (parametrized by iid Gaussian random variables) converging to $\dot{W}$ (cutting $[0,T] \times [0,L]$ in smaller and smaller rectangles)

Comment: Just like in you other question, $\dot W$ has a generalized meaning. E.g. your stochastic heat equation can be undertood as $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^L \phi(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)dx\, dt = \int_0^\infty \int_0^L \phi(x,t)  \dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t)dx\,dt  + \int_0^\infty \int_0^L \phi(x,t) f(u(x,t))W(dx,dt)
$$
for any suitable test function $\phi$.