# How does one derive the delta autocorrelation function for white noise?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

So I am a physicist, and in general I deal with so-called Langevin equations of the type
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t) +g(x,t)\xi(t),
\end{equation}
where $\xi(t)$ is what we call a "random Langevin force". In the case of white noise, this force is delta-correlated in time, such that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}\left[\xi(t)\xi(t')\right] = \delta(t-t').
\end{equation}
The Langevin equation can also be expressed in terms of the Ito equation
\begin{equation}
dx = f(x,t)dt+g(x,t)dW(t),
\end{equation}
where the Wiener process $dW(t)=\xi(t)dt$. Basically this means that
\begin{equation}
\xi(t) = \frac{dW(t)}{dt},
\end{equation}
even though technically the Wiener process is not differentiable. This is where things get confusing for me. I know that $\mathbf{E}[dW(t)] = 0$ and Var$[dW(t)] = dt$, but how exactly is it that $\xi(t)$ has delta autocorrelation? Is there a mathematical way to get to this result?
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}\left[\xi(t)\xi(t')\right] = \mathbf{E}\left[\frac{dW(t)}{dt}\frac{dW(t')}{dt'}\right] = \delta(t-t')\ ?
\end{equation}
I have looked everywhere in the literature and I can't see how this is obtained, it seems to be a detail that is glossed over all the time, especially in physics.

If $\xi(t)$ is truly represented as the rate of change in the Wiener process $W(t)$, then surely there must be a mathematical way to derive the result $\mathbf{E}\left[\xi(t)\xi(t')\right] = \delta(t-t')$ from the properties of $W(t)$ alone right?

Comment: The autocorrelation of BM $W(t)$ is $\operatorname{min}(s,t)$, which differentiated with respect to $s$ and $t$ yields $\delta(s-t)$.

Comment: @Tobsn do you have any links/books where that is shown? I am actually not familiar with that

Comment: e.g. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-540-36852-6%2F1.pdfv

Comment: @Tobsn Awesome, thanks, what book is this from? I might need to cite this on my work

Answer (score 1):

A formal connection with white noise is described in Le-Gall "Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus". See formal descriptions here [What is "white noise" and how is it related to the Brownian motion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639320/what-is-white-noise-and-how-is-it-related-to-the-brownian-motion) too that describe their unique connection.

If we use the distributional definition of white noise $\xi$

$$(\xi,\phi)=-\int B_{t}\phi'(t)dt,$$

then the covariance of white at two different times $S,T$ can be approximated by a normalized:

$$E\left[(\xi,1_{[S-\epsilon,S+\epsilon]})E(\xi,1_{[T-\epsilon,T+\epsilon]})\right]=E\left[\iint 1_{[S-\epsilon,S+\epsilon]]}(r)1_{[T-\epsilon,T+\epsilon]]}(t) dB_{r}dB_{t}\right]=\int 1_{[S-\epsilon,S+\epsilon]]\cap [T-\epsilon,T+\epsilon]]}(r)dr,$$

and so in the limit after normalizing by $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, we get $0$ or $+\infty$ depending on whether $S\neq T$ or $S= T$. (One has to mollify with compactly supported smooth functions $\phi_{\epsilon,S}(r),\phi_{\epsilon,T}(r)$).