# How to define colored noise or noise with correlation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

If I understand correctly, white noise refers to a Brownian motion that is independent at different locations: $E[\dot{B}_x\dot{B}_{x'}] = \delta_{x-x'}$.
Space-time white noise is independent in both time and space:
$$ E[\dot{B}(x,t) \dot{B}(x',t')] = \delta_{x-x'} \delta_{t-t'} \,.$$
(is that right?)

**Colored noise refers to noise that has some correlation with itself at different points and/or time. What exactly should that correlation be, and how can we define it?**

I know that white noise/brownian motion can be expanded into Fourier series, i.e. something like
$$ \frac{dW(t)}{dt} = \sum_{k=1}^n \eta_k \psi_k(t)$$
where $\eta_k \sim N(0,1)$ are iid and $\psi_k(t)$ are the Fourier basis functions. From this, how is colored noise defined? We could e.g. truncate the series, or introduce a weight term that makes makes larger-$k$ terms decay faster. What are the principles one would use in choosing different methods of approximation? I'm not sure how auto-correlation is related to the method of approximation.

Comment: You can have a look to [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise). Also, as far as I understand, white noise doesn't refer to a Brownian motion, but it can be obtained as the derivative of one (see, e.g, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639320/what-is-white-noise-and-how-is-it-related-to-the-brownian-motion?rq=1) or [this article](http://mbhauser.com/informal-notes/white-gaussian-noise.pdf)).

Comment: These concepts relate to the power spectrum density of the underlying noise. Which is the Fourier transform of the covariance of the process. The only agreed terminology is that white noise has a Dirac as it's covariance, so it's Fourier transform is a constant. Weakening this assumption/introducing small correlations are what is often what makes this go from white to coloured. However how someone does this is in a sense arbitrary and can lead to different notions. Some people like to use a nascent delta function, assume Gaussian + stationary in a wide sense. This gives you the OU process.

Comment: FYI, the covariance of B.M is the minimum of the two times, not a Dirac mass. You want a $\dot{B}_t$

Comment: There is no canonical definition of colored noise, it depends heavily on the use case. Let $(\phi_k)_k$ be a (piecewise) differentiable approximation of brownian motion such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}\phi_k(t)=B(t)$. Then every such $\dot{\phi}_k(t)$ is a colored noise, which of course depends on the underlying approximation.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis Thanks a lot. Would you explain more specifically how you introduce small correlations? I saw that the Brownian motion is more specifically written as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sigma_k \eta_k \psi(x)$ where in the uncorrelated case $\sigma_k$ is constant. If $\sigma_k$ decays, for example if $\sigma_k = 1/k$, we get a smoothening effect on the noise since higher-order terms decay. Is this an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Keine_Maschine thanks! In what ways do the definitions vary? Are they mainly built off of the Fourier description of white noise, and how so?

Comment: @900edges There is no mathematical precise definition afaik. You can build them from fourier series via truncating the infinite series. You may be interested in Karhunen-Loeve expansion. An other approach is to approximate colored noise via interpolation of white noise/brownian motion.

Comment: @900edges the approach I was referring to (and again, this is by no means the only way or most common way) is to replace the identity $\mathbb{E}[\xi_t \xi_s] = \delta(t-s)$ (which is basically saying the correlation is identically zero except at the same time) by a "small correlation" $\mathbb{E}[\xi^\epsilon_t \xi^\epsilon_s] = F^\varepsilon(t-s)$ where $F^\epsilon$ gets very small away from 0. 

One can show that if $F^\epsilon(\cdot) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}F(\cdot / \epsilon)$ and $F$ is continuous with compact support, it limits to the Dirac.

Comment: (cont) Note by making the assumption of $t-s$ dependence on $F$ I am assuming stationarity in a wide sense of my coloured noise $\xi^\epsilon$. I can (arbitrarily) make other "nice assumptions" like being Gaussian, and being a diffusion process, which if you buy this, forces this definition of coloured noise to be the solution of $d \xi^\epsilon = \epsilon^{-2} A \xi^\epsilon + \epsilon^{-1} B dW$. So from these assumptions we introduced a param $\epsilon$ that decides how far away you are form being a dirac, and thus perfectly uncorrelated noise.