# Convolution process with gaussian white noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, convolution

A Gaussian process $z(s)$ can  be established by convolving a gaussian white noise process $x(s)$ with a smoothing kernel $k(s)$ http://ftp.stat.duke.edu/WorkingPapers/01-03.pdf

$$z(s)=\int_{S}^{} \! k(u-s) x(u).du \ \  \text{where } s\in R $$

As a result, the covariance between any two points $s$ and $s'$ can be expressed as follows

$$ c(s, s')=\int_{S}^{} \! k(u-s) k(u-s').du= \int_{S}^{} \! k(u-(s-s')) k(u).du$$

I need help understanding two issues :

1) white noise process is discontinuous and thus Riemann integration cannot be used in the first equation

2) How is the covariance equation derived

3) How did $s'$ jump to the first kernel

Comment: The input process should not necessarily be Gaussian.

Comment: @msm Yup i understand that, but in the case that $x(s)$ is a gaussian white noise, how are these equations derived ? thanks

Comment: a white noise is a random i.i.d. zero mean sequence $W_n$.  The "continuous" analog doesn't exists (the limit when the sample rate $\to \infty$) but there is the Wiener process $B(t)$ , whose "derivative" is such a white noise with infinite sample rate : $B(t) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n =1}^{\lfloor N t \rfloor} W_n}{\sqrt{N}}$ (the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ is necessary for $\mathbb{E}[ |B(t+a)-B(t)|^2] = a\mathbb{E}[|W_n|^2]$). $\quad$ So what I mean is that you can convoluate $B(t)$ with $k'(t)$ and you should get the covariance you'd like

Comment: @user1952009. Thank you. My question is related to the gaussian white noise $x(u)$. In the first page of the paper linked, an illustration of convoltution with white noise is provided. I dont understand how this integral is managed and how they derived the covariance

Comment: read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Continuous-time_white_noise  and think to the continuous white noise of your paper and the $w(t)$ of wiki as the derivative of my $B(t)$ (that isn't defined, but it isn't a problem since $B \ast k'(t)$ is) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process

Comment: @user1952009 please can you please elaborate more on how the covariance is then derived.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1912591/532409 "Convolute White noise"

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134011/445105 Scalar product with white noise is closely related to convolutions

Answer (score 1):

White noise can only be defined in the sense of distributions or as a measure. A good definition can be found in [Adler and Taylor (2007, Sec. 1.4.3)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-48116-6), see also [this SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719865/445105).

To calculate second moments you want to use stochastic integration [Adler and Taylor (2007, sec. 5.2)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-48116-6) (also see below) for deterministic functions $f,g$
$$
\mathbb{E}[W(f)W(g)]
\overset{\text{def.}}=\mathbb{E}\Bigl[\Bigl(\int f(x)W(dx)\Bigr)\Bigl(\int g(x)W(dx)\Bigr) \Bigr]
=\int f(x)g(x) dx, \tag{1}
$$
which can be viewed as a special case of the [Itô Isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry).

### Convolution

We can consider convolutions as a special case
$$
    (f*W)(t) = \int f(t-s)W(ds) = W(f(t-\cdot))
$$
then the covariance function (expectation is zero) is given by
$$
    C(t,s) = \mathbb{E}[ (f*W)(t)(f*W)(s)] =  \int f(t-x)f(s-x)dx
$$

## Stochastic Integration

The trick to prove (1), is to show that the mapping
$$
W:\begin{cases}
      L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}, \nu) 
      &\to L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})\\
      f &\mapsto W(f) := \int f(t) W(dt)
\end{cases}
$$
preserves the scalar product.
We first consider simple functions $f=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mathbf{1}_{A_i}$ for disjoint $A_i$, then
$$
   W(f)=\int f(t) W(dt) \overset{\text{def.}}= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i W(A_i)
$$

> Comment: in particular the expectation is zero and variance given by $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \nu(A_i)$ considering the [definition of $W$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719865/445105).

To calculate the scalar product between $f$ and $g=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \mathbf{1}_{B_i}$ we assume without loss of generality $A_i=B_i$ (consider all of their interesections). Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle W(f), W(g) \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{P})} 
&= \mathbb{E}\Bigl[\sum_{i=1}^n a_i W(A_i) \sum_{j=1}^n a_j W(A_j)\Bigr]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \mathbb{E}[W(A_i)^2]\\
&= \int f(t) g(t) \nu(dt)\\
&= \langle f, g\rangle_{L^2(\nu)}
\end{aligned}$$
Since the simple function are dense in $L^2$ and the scalar product is continuous we can deduce that $W$ is an isometry (where $W(f)$ for general $f$ is defined as the limit of $W(f_n)$ for simple functions $f_n$ approximating $f$). (1) then directly follows from the respective definitions of the scalar product (i.e. the second and penultimate term).