# Convolute White noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, convolution, signal-processing

In the famous paper Higdon (2002) http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.26.5356&rep=rep1&type=pdf

It is stated that a Gaussian process is established by convolving a convolving a gaussian white noise process $x(s)$ with a smoothing kernel $k(s)$. Like the one in the figure below

$$z(s)=\int_{S}^{} \! k(u-s) x(u).du \ \  \text{where } s\in R $$

White noise is discontinuous and Riemann integration cannot be used. What are the asusmptions here ? Can anyone help me understand the intuition

[Link to Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlYG1.jpg)

Comment: Umm the link says a continuous white noise process. (section 2 paragraph 1 just before equation1)

Comment: @KitterCatter what is a continuous gausssian white noise process, how is it defined ? and how does it differ from typical gaussian white noise ? thanks

Comment: Looking it up:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Continuous-time_white_noise
Essentially it follows the normal rules of white noise, but rather than a Kronecker Delta in the expectation value you end up with a dirac delta.

Comment: @KitterCatter I have read the wikipedia page, I cant understand how the dirac delta function is able to construct integerability

Comment: Worth checking: "Convolution process with gaussian white noise" https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1911580/532409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first paper and book will answer your question will answer your question

1) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375897001626

2) Yaglom, A.M., 1987. Correlation Theory of Stationary and Related Random Functions I: Basic Results.
Springer, New York.

PS: You also might want to look at stable linear filters which poses the same  question

Answer (score 0):

The Higdon paper defines Gaussian white noise as i.i.d. normal distributions (of zero mean) on a discrete lattice of points, and takes a limit as the lattice spacing goes to zero *and the variance of the distributions decreases like the square root of the lattice distance*.  This is a lot like ways to define Brownian motion.

As to whether the paper properly treats the limit as $d \to 0$, I can't verify that myself but the paper's referees would presumedly have caught any unjustified steps.

Comment: Isnt this the way to define a continuous white noise ?