# Covariance of white noise smoothed by convolution with a squared exponential kernel

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, convolution, noise

Determine the autocovariance
$$
    C(s,t) = \text{Cov}(X(s), X(t))
$$
of white noise $W$ convolved with a squared exponential (Gaussian) kernel $\phi$
$$
X(t) = (\phi* W) (t) = \int \phi(t-x) W(dx)
$$
where the squared exponential kernel is given by
$$
\phi(x) = \exp\bigl(-\frac{\|x\|^2}{2\beta}\bigr)
$$
and white noise is [defined as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719865/445105).

The result was used [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446397/just-how-regular-are-the-sample-paths-of-1d-white-noise-smoothed-with-a-gaussian).

Answer (score 0):

From the answer to the question [Scalar product of a deterministic function with Gaussian white noise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719921/445105), we know that
$$
C(s,t) = \mathbb{E}[\langle \phi(s-\cdot), W\rangle\langle \phi(t-\cdot), W\rangle] 
= \int \phi(s-x)\phi(t-x)dx
$$
So we only need to calculate
$$\begin{aligned}
\phi(s-x)\phi(t-x)
&= \exp\Bigl(-\frac{\|s-x\|^2 + \|t-x\|^2}{2\beta}\Bigr)\\
&= \exp\Bigl(-\frac{\|s\|^2 + \|t\|^2 - 2\langle t+s, x\rangle + 2\|x\|^2}{2\beta}\Bigr)\\
&= \exp\Bigl(-\frac{
   \tfrac12\|s - t\|^2 +\tfrac12\|s+t\|^2 - 2\langle t+s, x\rangle + 2\|x\|^2
}{2\beta}\Bigr)\\
&= \exp\Bigl(
   -\frac{\tfrac12\|s - t\|^2 
   + \bigl\|\frac{s+t}{\sqrt{2}} - \sqrt{2} x\bigr\|^2 }{2\beta}
\Bigr)\\
&= \exp\Bigl(
   -\frac{\tfrac12\|s - t\|^2}{2\beta}\Bigr)
\exp\Bigl(-\frac{2\bigl\|\frac{s+t}{2} - x\bigr\|^2 }{2\beta}
\Bigr)
\end{aligned}
$$
This finally implies
$$
C(s,t) = \exp\bigl(-\tfrac1{4\beta}\|s - t\|^2\bigr)
\underbrace{\int\exp\Bigl(-\frac{\bigl\|\frac{s+t}{2} - x\bigr\|^2 }{2(\beta/2)}\Bigr) dx}_{=\sqrt{(\beta\pi)^d}} = (\beta \pi)^{d/2} \exp\bigl(-\tfrac1{4\beta}\|s - t\|^2\bigr)
$$